# Two way socket communication

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to write a simple two way socket communication using C. So far, the main while loop for my client.c file looks like this:

```
while ( gets(str) != NULL ) {
sSize = send(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
if ( len != strlen(str) ) {
  exit(1);
}

else {
   rSize  =  recv(s, buffer, 64, 0);
   buf[rSize] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
 }
}
```

while loop in sever.c looks like this:

```
while ( 1 ) {
gets(str);
send(p, str, strlen(str), 0);

  rSize = recv(p, buffer, 32, 0);   
  if ( rSize < 0 ) {
    exit(1);
  }
 buf[len] = '\0';
  else{
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
  }
}
```

The program compiles normally and I can establish connection between both machines, but when I send message either from client or server, I get an anomaly:

Sending message 'hi' from client

```
client -------------------------- server
hi
```

If I go to server to send 'you' message, I get:

```
client -------------------------- server
hi                           
                                  you
you                               hi
```

Not sure exactly how this is, but what I'm trying to achieve is that, whenever message is sent from either client or server, it should display immediately on the other side.

Comment: You should state what you expected and why this isn't what you expected. It seems to me like your program is doing exactly what it should. Each side inputs a message, and then the two sides exchange messages.

Comment: If `recv()` returns zero you should stop reading from the socket, close it, and go and do something else, or exit. The peer has disconnected.

Comment: Note well that data is far more important than code and much more difficult to get right.  You did not post the declarations for items such as str, len, buffer.   Example of issue: how are we to know that your buffer is at least 65 long unless you show us?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that gets() is a blocking function. Initially both client and server are blocked in gets() waiting for input. When you type 'hi' on client, it sends this to the server which is still blocked on gets.

After sending hi, the client blocks on recv() call, waiting for message from server. On the other side, server hasn't still received the 'hi' message send by the client.

When you type 'you' on the server, it comes out of gets() and sends 'you' to client. After that the server calls recv() and reads the 'hi' sent by the client. Since the client is already waiting in recv(), it reads 'you' sent by the server.

Thus the program is working absolutely the way it has been implemented. Please mention your object, not sure what do you want to achieve.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is that, each message sent should deliver as it is sent.

Comment: In that case you need to poll on socket and stdin. Please refer to the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900984/c-using-poll-to-multiplex-between-sockets-and-stdin-server